# Security concern: Azure AKS omsagent pod running as root user. How to apply additional hardening?

Tags: security, azure-aks

As described here: https://github.com/microsoft/Docker-Provider/issues/371

We are concerned about that the omsagent is running as root user, due to that the omsagent is accessing /var/log on the AKS-Cluster nodes.

Does anyone have comments on this? Is the omsagent "safe"? What can be done to improve the security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the [network requirements for omsagent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/container-insights-onboard#network-firewall-requirements), it shows that `omsagent` requires only outbound access via port 443 to send data to the Log Analytics workspace.

Depending on your security posture, a service which does not accept incoming connections can be considered "safe" or at least "safer" than an externally available service.